# Message after a data is inserted

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

How to make a message appear in the top of the page when a form has been submitted and a record has been inserted in mysql below is my action.php page.

```
<?php $email =$_POST["email"];
include "includes/db_config.php";

$sql = "INSERT INTO subscribers(email)
VALUES('$email')";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
  header('location:index.php?subscribe=yes');

} else {
    echo "Failed" .  $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}


?>
```

and then at index.php

```
<?php
    if ($_GET['subscribe'] =='yes'){
    echo 'You succesully subscribe to our exclusive promos';
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: What is the problem with the given code? It's vulnerable to SQL injection, but looks fine otherwise

Comment: the message wont appear in the top

Comment: Then why don't you structure your code such that this happens, Using CSS or changing the PHP code such that this echo is the first thing to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JavaScript alert box in page `index.php` for this purpose.

```
<?php
    if ($_GET['subscribe'] =='yes'){
       echo '<script language="javascript">';
       echo 'alert("Form has been submitted")';
       echo '</script>';
    }
?>
```

Hope it helps.